# Reading the string with defined number of characters from the input

Tags: c, string, scanf

So I am trying to read a defined number of characters from the input. Let's say that I want to read 30 characters and put them in to a string. I managed to do this with a **for loop**, and I cleaned the buffer as shown below.

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++){
     string[i]=getchar();
}
string[30]='\0';
while(c!='\n'){
     c=getchar();       // c is some defined variable type char 
 }
```

And this is working for me, but I was wondering if there is another way to do this. I was researching and some of them are using `sprintf()` for this problem, but I didn't understand that solution. Then I found that you can use `scanf` with `%s`. And some of them use `%3s` when they want to read 3 characters. I tried this myself, but this command only reads the string till the first empty space. This is the code that I used:

```
scanf("%30s",string);
```

And when I run my program with this line, if I for example write: "Today is a beatiful day. It is raining, but it's okay i like rain." I thought that the first 30 characters would be saved in to the string. But when i try to read this string with `puts(string);` it only shows "Today".

If I use `scanf("%s",string)` or `gets(string)` that would rewrite some parts of my memory if the number of characters on input is greater than 30.

Answer (score 1):

The API you're looking for is [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). The man page describes

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`
>
> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than `size` characters from `stream` and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf("%30[^\n]",s)`

Actually, this is how you can set which characters to input. Here, carat sign `'^'` denotes `negation`, ie. this will input all characters except `\n`. `%30` asks to input 30 characters. So, there you are.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful.